# Interfacing to bill/coin acceptors and printers

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, printing, hardware, coin-change

I have been approached regarding building a touch screen app for a client, but as it will be for use on kiosk machine it needs to interface with a bill/coin acceptor and a printer.

What are the common the ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all if you will be doing it with AS3, anyway it need to run somewhere, i mean OS. Usualy it is Linux or Windows.

2nd The app will be more interface. More about printing you can find here: http://goo.gl/5qoy6

3th can not tell anything about bill / coin acceptor but there somewhere between that and your App should be another application which sends data to Aapp and gets orders from App what should the acceptor do. ( or it is the acceptors software allready )

Comment: Thanks, Yes I will be using a window box I think - purely because I haven't really used Linux much. So it seems printing hopefully wont be the issue, but more communication with bill / coin acceptor. I guess I would use a socket connection to another app that communicates with the bill acceptor